# "User was removed" message in reputation log

Tags: support, faq, reputation

What kind of system event is that which results in my reputation decreased with a message: "-10 User was removed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user account has been deleted, and the reputation you gained from the votes given from that user have been removed.

Comment: The user was a user in time of voting up, why SE remove it's given reputation?